# Calculate time spend in a state using hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am working on a hive query where I need to calculate the time spent by a user in a state.

The data looks something like this:

[image]

I am trying to get the output like this:

[image]

I tried the script like this:

```
   select
    case when a.oldstatus = Registered and b.newstatus in 
    ('Active','Suspended','Reactive')  then              
     b.stats_changets-a.statuschagets
       ... so on for each state
     end status,
     count(*) as WithinXRange
   from
   MyTable a,b 
   where a.id = b.id
   group by event_dt
```

So the b.statuschgts - a.statuschgts gives us or no of days which in turn I use in query to put it in different buckets as shown in 2nd image.

Can you please help me with this query.

Comment: Can you please explain the output?

Comment: So basically I am trying to calculate the no of days spent by each user in a state. Like say A1 spend 4 days in registered state and now he has moved to suspended state. output value should be 4 which lies in 4-6 days range.